# Printing with printing driver options pre selected

Tags: javascript, php, printing

For the last couple of days my boss and I, have this problem where we need to print a `html` page but with some setting pre set. Baically its 4 A4s papers to be printed on A3 but in a booklet sort of way. I am using `HTML`, `CSS` and `javascript` together with `PHP` to generate that page.

Now when I call the window.print() method I can change it to landscape and A3 but I have to go to the printer's preferences to change Binding position to Right Bind so it will be printed in a booklet sort of way. Employees at the moment do that manually but its becoming frustrating and they would like the option that these settings are pre set for them.

1. A3
2. Landscape
3. Binding Position: Right Bind.

Now I know and understand why `Javascript` is not given access to the printers preferences for security reasons but I am sure there must be a way with another language or technique to do that.

On a site note if it helps, the printer is Konica Minolta bizhub C258 and it is connected to our network as well.

The server used is Linux.

Any help greatly appreciated.